# Javacard scriptgen

Tags: javacard

I try to use the oracle java card development kit 3.0.5u2 command line tools.

1. I use the cap file generated by netbeans
2. I use `verifycap.bat` on my cap together with the export files in the api_export_files directory of the sdk.

   ```
   verifycap.bat -nobanner -nowarn ..\api_export_files\javacard\framework\javacard\framework.exp ..\api_export_files\javacard\security\javacard\security.exp ..\api_export_files\java\lang\javacard\lang.exp kaylat.cap > kaylat.hash
   ```

I get a hash file with this content:

```
[ INFO: ]  [v3.0.5] Off-Card Verifier, Version {1}.
[ INFO: ]     Copyright (c) 1998, 2017, Oracle and/or its affiliates. All rights reserved.


[ INFO: ] Vérification du fichier CAP kaylat.cap
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/ConstantPool.cap     [SHA-256: ad9ece95c64174d87b92488213081d1f977c975ba116fd7dead60246a1a94099]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/StaticField.cap      [SHA-256: 5863e9740af5fb905922380b2aa88309a16a285dd3412417ae8af941327901ee]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Descriptor.cap       [SHA-256: 957c5fd5ebee857a06b38129d5b94b3a0bf155d989c6db4080bc8f0ec2c26606]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Header.cap       [SHA-256: 67802c08d73cee2e77947b76dd5f5f728055fec8c9ab4820369b18f845bb4eab]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Directory.cap        [SHA-256: 803ba29574f2013b4dc895253afaf0bc8376deb1110eb35ee90c6e6807b70a59]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Applet.cap       [SHA-256: 17b671b4e2371e00eea2717f84cb016baa818a92c46687e25b5392023a071229]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Method.cap       [SHA-256: 9e7dd02202e95de04a33fd812f1ab38cf5554ee1ee3c0d982d31140c1313f97f]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Class.cap        [SHA-256: f788cc84d355e9a2cda8432c6af815aad6ed5574b5246641122158167850c6dc]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/RefLocation.cap      [SHA-256: 16e7d9445917130b643bee62728b460c37511ce12b5c65c7653f9f75b8fa5df6]
[ INFO: ] Hash for kaylat/javacard/Import.cap       [SHA-256: ce4ee9399ef89f122c68620d0330239a0f40a178992aae6c60fdf02caa492817]
[ INFO: ] 0 warnings and 0 errors.
```

3. I run scriptgen.bat:

   ```
   scriptgen.bat kaylat.cap -hashfile kaylat.hash
   ```

This command fails with message:

```
Missing hash for required component: header.cap
```

Comment: scriptgen is present twice in step 3: copy paste error?

Comment: Step 3 I run scriptgen command: scriptgen.bat kaylat.cap -hashfile kaylat.hash

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of redirecting the output of verifycap.bat to a file ("> kaylat.hash"), you should probably use the program option "-outfile <file-name>", which will write the digest values in the correct format to the file. Then use this file for input to scriptgen.bat. 
If I use the console output of the program as input to the scriptgen.bat, I get the same error. If I use the -outfile option, all works fine.

```
C:\verifycap.bat
[ INFO: ] Usage: verifycap [options] <export files> <CAP file>
                               (or)
                 verifycap <-C | --commandoptionsfile> <command options file>
  Where options include:
  -digest <alg-name>   specify the digest to use (default: SHA-256)
  -help                Print this message and exit.
  -nobanner            Suppress banner message.
  -nowarn              Suppress warning messages.
  -outfile <file-name> Specify the name of the output file to store digest (default: no output file created)
  -package <pkg>       Set the name of the package to be verified
  -verbose             Turn on verbose mode.
  -version             Print version number and exit.
```